# Does the Sun produce audible sound?

Tags: astronomy, acoustics, sun, frequency

Theoretically if I were able to build some sort of device that let me sit 1 foot away from the surface of the Sun (or any star for that matter) without being vaporized, would a star produce any sort of audible sound at that distance?   From my understanding, sound waves need a medium to propagate through (air, water, etc).   Does this mean that all stars are completely silent (in the audible spectrum of frequencies at least) as they fuse  hydrogen into helium?   I know stars emit radio, xray, infrared, ultraviolet electromagnetic waves, but how about audible (20 Hz to 20Khz) frequencies?   For some reason it seems like this process would produce some sort of sound.

Comment: I'm sure it's pretty loud at the sun's surface. But out in space there's probably not much sound, since the molecule density is so low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[helioseismology](http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/Helioseismology.shtml) is what you need to learn about. yes, there are sound waves in Sun

Comment: totally not the answer I was expecting!   thank you for the link!

Comment: While the p-modes are pressure waves just like normal acoustic oscillations, their frequencies are something like 3 mHz, so they don't really correspond to "sound" in the colloquial sense.

Answer (score 2):

The surface of the sun is where local plasma cools enough to recombine and go transparent, the photosphere.  You would still be deep within the sun's atmosphere, and it would be LOUD.  H-bombs are LOUD at the edge of their fireballs.

[image: Photosphere of star]

Comment: Have you ever sat at the edge of an H-bomb's fireball? Did you work on the Tsar Bomba project :) ?

Comment: We have physics so we can estimate within factor of 10 rather than suffer grad students or technicians complaining about field trips.  "8^>)

Comment: The Sun is not an H-bomb. The fusion reaction in an H-bomb procedes very rapidly, but fusion in the Sun is *very* slow: it takes billions of years, on average, for a proton in the solar core to successfully undergo fusion.